# PHP - Avoid typing much lines

Tags: php

So I want to avoid typing 9999 possible outcomes doing something like this:

```
if($experience==50) {echo 'level 2'; }
if($experience==300) {echo 'level 3'; }
if($experience==700) {echo 'level 4'; }
if($experience==1000) {echo 'level 5'; }
```

Is there a way to do it? So yes i hope somebody could help me!

**EDIT:** The max level is 99 so i have also to check 
`if($level == 1 && $experience >= 50) { echo 'level 2';}`

Comment: An array with the experience as the key and the level as the value ?

Comment: @André - I hope you don't mean an array for each possible experience value. :P

Comment: Is there a formula which related the level and the experience? Or do you set 9999 values on a whim?

Comment: What level is someone with 51 experience?

Comment: If there is any kind of relation (mathematical) between the points and level, then yes, you could cover arbitrarily many levels in very few lines. Your example seems random, though.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: You can't.

Long answer: You must create the experience map somewhere. In code or in a settings file/database. The system can't magical know how to map the experience to levels without you telling it how to.

What you can do however is to create a formula on how the levels are linked to experiences then it's just a small calculation and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed to `@Ztripez HellströmYou's` answer. You need some kind of math formula, I would do something like:

```
$level = 1;
// level up after every 50 * $currentLevel xp gained
if ($experience >= 50 && $experience % (50*$level) == 0 && $level <= 99) {
   $level++;
}

echo 'Level: ' . $level;
```

So above would result in the following:

```
$level = 1;
$experience = 50;

After if condition, $level = 2

$level = 2;
$experience = 95;

After if condition, $level = 2 //not increased

$level = 2;
$experience = 100;

After if condition, 100 % (50*2) == 0 ? true - $level = 3

etc...
```

**Note:** make sure to increase XP points by multiples of 5 so you dont go over the threshold. Or increase it by multiples of `50` or multiples of `10`.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, EXP-level thresholds are calculated on some kind of formula. Often this formula is exponential in nature, so you might have something like:

```
$base = 50;
$growth = 1.2;
$maxlevel = 100;
$levelthresholds = array();
for( $i=0; $i<$maxlevel; $i++) $levelthresholds[$i] = $base*$i*pow($growth,$i-1);
// the above is a formula I've used in many places, it works quite well
```

The base rate would be your EXP for Level 2, then the growth is how much you multiply the base rate by to get the next level. With `1.2`, you'd get:

> Level 1: 0
>   Level 2: 50
>   Level 3: 120
>   Level 4: 216
>   Level 5: 345
>   ...

You can adapt your `$base` and `$growth` rates as desired. You can also use something like using a lower `$base`, `round`ing the result and then multiplying by `100` to get nice, rounded numbers.

The point here is to determine a formula for EXP, as this greatly reduces the amount of code you have to write. Once done you can do this:

```
for( $level = 0; $level < $maxlevel; $level++) {
    if( $levelthresholds[$level] > $experience) break;
}
$level++; // result should be 1-based
```

Comment: Couldn't you just use log()?

Comment: @JimmyT. Only if your function is a simple exponentiation. The one I use is sort of "exponential plus".

Comment: You can still create an inverse function.

Comment: @JimmyT. If you can create an inverse function for `y = 50 * x * (1.2^x)`, let me know!